# Как конвертировать картинки в webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, webpack4, webp

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы `webpack` в `dev` сборке компилировал картинки только тогда когда я добавлю новую картинку, и ту которую добавил. Ещё чтобы аналогично работал плагин [imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin), то есть конвертировал когда добавлю новую и ту которую добавил.
Вот мой [git repo](https://github.com/SergeiWeb/webpack%22) со сборкой.
P. S. На данном этапе плагин конвертации картинок очень тормозит сборку, каждый раз приходится ждать в среднем 50 секунд. Я пробовал запускать плагин конвертации только в `prod` и вроде все норм, но хочу узнать есть какой-то способ делать это в `dev` без всяких проблем. Ещё столкнулся с такой проблемой что как-то глючит Vs code когда работает dev сборка, особенно файл `index.html`.
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с этими проблемами, а то я уже 3 день разбираюсь и хороших результатов не добился